# Microsoft PKI Certificate validity period shorter than what is defined in Template

Tags: powershell, ssl, certificate, pki, mmc

Issue:
I have created a new template for Web Servers and if I use the MMC Snap-In called "Certificates", then select "Local Machine", the snap-in comes up. I then follow the UI and can clearly see my template and am able to successfully enroll via AD and my certificate installs with no problem.

The issue here is that when I do the above, the certificate is good for 2 years (just like I set it in the validity period). However, I am trying to script this process and "Get-Certificate" kept giving me an error I couldn't figure out so I am using the "certreq" command line tool.

When I use this tool, I am able to get a certificate but its validity period is set to 1 year instead of 2. I get this error every time (even when I use Admin account on the CA or Sub-CA):
"The certificate validity period will be shorter than the Web_Server-Primary Certificate Template specifies, because the template validity period is longer than the maximum cer
tificate validity period allowed by the CA.  Consider renewing the CA certificate, reducing the template validity period, or increasing the registry validity period."

I have checked and re-checked the validity period and still can't get this to work. I have done this now many times and every time I use MMC, it works like it should. But when I use "certreq", I get the error. I also specifically state which Sub-CA to use to ensure the processes are as identical as possible.

Has anyone had to deal with something like this before?

Comment: disregard. Checked again and found 1 of the sub-ca's was setup with a certificate that did in fact have only 1 year validity. Was just odd that MMC worked fine but that's attributable to the fact that the CA and the other sub-CA were setup correctly.

Comment: And I would delete but don't know how :(